# iReport Line and Bar in same chart

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using iReport to try to create a chart for bug tracking.  I need a stacked bar chart for the different severities of the open bugs by day and a line showing the total number of bugs by day.  It's easy enough to build a multi-axis chart but it always shows up with distinct ranges on the Y axis.  I want the Y axis to be the same range so that the total bugs line floats above the stacked open bugs bars.  This is simple to do in Excel or Crystal Reports but I cannot see a way to do this in iReport.  I need to be able to either merge Y axis in a multi-axis report or be able to change the series type of one of the series from stacked bar to line.  Any tips/reading materials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice if it were more automated, but you can use a solution like this pretty easily:

Instead of calculating the Range Axis height automatically, create your own variable to decide an appropriate value for the maximum value. Then you can set the Range Axis Max Value to the same thing for both charts.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea.  Worked like a charm once I removed the ticks and scales and such from everything but a single chart.

Comment: Just messed around a shameful number of hours with the thousands of options of the jasper-charting engine, just to display the top-y-values of a bar chart and some line charts at the right position. Your answer was the key. It isn't obvious that in a multi-axis-chart the range axis-maximum is a different one for every axis, and not the maximum overall. The ${Variable} is the key for this. Upvote.